# Making Requests using tkinter works differently than terminal

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

I created a program that does some webscraping. If give the link as as a variable it runs fine, but if I type it into the tkinter.Text(), and use `.get('1.0', 'end')`, it doesn't work (returns <Response [404]>). Does anyone know the reason for this?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - some inputs that should and shouldn't work, and the outputs that you're expecting and actually getting from each input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.get('1.0', 'end')` there is \n at the end of your string - that because your link is uncorrect. Maybe try to use `.get('1.0', 'end')[:-1]`

Comment: Tkinter makes it easy to limit what you get without resorting to trimming the string afterwords. `.get('1.0', 'end-1c')` will ever everything up to the end minus one character.